# Issue while reading the parameter from URL with '&'

Tags: jquery

I am reading parameters from URL for my search app using the following code.

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
 results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

How this works is I pass a 'q' parameter, which is the search query, and then display it on the page in the refine search box. It works fine for normal cases, i.e.

if the **q=this is testing**, the term 'this is testing' will get added to the refine search box and user can keep on refining the search, but if **q=this & that**, i.e. if it contains '&' then at first, this will be added in the refine search box as **this & that**, but when I refine the search, it becomes **this** and **& that** is stripped off, and the query becomes 'this'.

Any help?

Comment: You're testing with invalid URLs...

Comment: if you use & in a url, that normally means a new variable is being passed.

Comment: Then how should i handle the query with '&'?

Comment: The `&`'s that are in the URL should only be related to a key value pair. No well-formed URL will have an `&` as part of a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to percentage encode the ampersand in order to use it in a URL..

You've probally seen this in URL's before.. An ampersand this way will come in as %26

http://www.asciitable.com/
adding any of these codes with % beforehand will come in as plaintext in the querystring.

http://www.eso.org/~ndelmott/url_encode.html